Next.js Deployment Issue - "Module not found" Error on Vercel
I'm encountering a deployment issue with my Next.js project. While it functions perfectly in the local development environment, I'm getting "Module not found" errors for some components when deploying to Vercel.
Steps Taken:
Local Build Success: I've confirmed that the local build process (npm run build) completes successfully.
Troubleshooting Attempts: I've tried various troubleshooting methods, including Gemini, but haven't identified the root cause yet.
Error Messages:
[19:10:28.477] ./src/app/panel/newProject/page.jsx
[19:10:28.477] Module not found: Can't resolve '@/components/multistepForm/MultistepForm'
[19:10:28.478] ./src/app/about/page.jsx
[19:10:28.478] Module not found: Can't resolve '@/components/postContainer/PostContainer'
Additional Information:
Next.js Version: 14.0.4
Vercel Deployment Logs (provided above)
Question:
I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve the "Module not found" error for PostContainer specifically. Have you encountered similar issues in Next.js deployments, and what potential solutions could I explore?

its likely that your alias setup is misconfigured with a conflicting path(s); meaning the referenced path may be overlapping with another alias. For additional information in alias setup though generic. Please review: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/absolute-imports-and-module-aliases

Thank you for the response.
I don't think so, this is how my jsconfig.json file looks:
{ "compilerOptions": { "paths": { "prop-types": ["./node_modules/prop-types"], "@/": ["./src/"] } } }
The paths, exports, and imports within the files themselves seem to be correct.

Additionally, I'm using other components and pages with the same import syntax from similar paths, and it's not causing any issues, so I'm not really sure what the problem is.

thanks for replying but, thats not the correct setup. It should be the following: "compilerOptions": { "paths": { "prop-types/*": ["./node_modules/prop-types/*"], "@/*": ["./src/*"] } } } your missing  asterisk(s) - Alternatively, you can also look into configuring the next.config.js file and include WebPack configuration and rollup dependencies or assets. Info can be found here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/webpack

"Thanks for your help! The problem was a case-sensitive typo in my import statement. I really appreciate your assistance."
